# How edit .sql file in windows (excel)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, excel

I'm not very expert in SQL, i just want edit some tables on my website's phpmyadmin and it takes a lot of time.so I want to export the sql file and edit it on Microsoft excel or any similar tools, but i didn't find any solution to open the sql file in excel and didn't find any similar tools. Do you know any solution to open sql in excel or what tool i should to use for this purpose?

Comment: You're trying to edit SQL scripts or the Tables directly? What kind of changes? Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I want to change some values in sql table from my website's phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm assuming you're using MySQL since you're talking about phpMyAdmin. I removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag and added the MySQL tag, feel free to revert if I'm wrong. Unfortunately this is a *shopping list* type of question and not appropriate for this website. What you're trying to do isn't exactly possible. But what will probably make your life easier to edit the table is to use a SQL editor, like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

Comment: Visual Studio? https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/